# Why don't my meta tags work (manually uploading individual HTML files)?

Tags: html, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I've searched around and can't find any solutions to why my `meta` tags don't work.  I'm manually uploading my html files into my public_html folder so I'm guessing that I'm missing a file or piece of code that would make my tags work, or maybe I'm missing something simple in the prefix.

If there's a separate protocol I should use then I'm certainly open to it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Code:

```
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="My description" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.myimageurl.com/image.png" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myurl.com" />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@https://www.myurl.com/-UserName" />
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
        <meta name="linkedin:mini" content="true">
        <meta name="twitter:img:src" content="https://www.myimageurl.com/image.png" />
        <meta name="twitter:image:width" content= "1200" />
        <meta name="twitter:image:height" content= "630" />
     </head>
```

Comment: Are you using a debug tool: https://www.opengraphcheck.com/ . You may simply need to force refresh the debugger to ensure it doesn't cache an expired version of your page.

Comment: Using browser developer tools you can [disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/10441671) to see your changes immediately. Otherwise it depends on your browser's local cache when the live content will be visible.

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.